# R: calculating sample size based on hypergeometric distribution

Tags: r, statistics, sampling

Suppose there are 1000 marbles in a hat, and 100 are red. How many marbles do I need to draw (without replacement) in order to have at least 40 red marbles? I am looking at [this formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113436/formula-for-calculating-sample-size-for-hypergeometric-distribution) here, but I was wondering if R has a built in function for calculating sample sizes like these. I've looked at functions such as `dhyper`, `phyper`, etc, but it seems like these do not calculate the sample size.